# R: save ggplot2 plots in different excel sheets

Tags: r, ggplot2, openxlsx

I am using R package ggplot2 to create plots of different groups. Then, I want to export these plots to an excel file with different worksheets. I used the following code:

```
List1 <- split(df, df$Group) #Split data frame by group
ListGraphs <- lapply(List1, function(x) ggplot(x, aes(x=Quintiles, y=Perc, group=Answer, color=as.factor(Answer)))+
              geom_line(size=2)
              theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom", legend.key = element_blank())) #Create a plot for each element of the list
wb <- createWorkbook() #Create an Excel workbook 
for (s in seq_along(ListGraphs)){
name <- addWorksheet(wb,names(ListGraphs[s])) #Add worksheets with group names
insertPlot(wb, name)} #insert plots in the excel sheets
saveWorkbook(wb,"a.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE) #Save workbook
```

However, this is not working. I have an excel file with multiple sheets and the same plot in each one of them. I think the problem is when I save the plots in a list because it creates a list of lists. But I don't have any idea about what I should change here. Could anyone help me?

Here is an example of my data frame(df):

```
  Quintiles Group    Answer   Perc
1 1          1       1        96 
2 1          1       4        4 
3 1          2       4        4 
4 2          2       5        96 
5 2          3       1        64 
6 3          3       2        8 
7 3          3       3        28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help of `insertPlot`: *The **current plot** is saved to a temporary image file using dev.copy. This file is then written to the workbook using insertImage*.
This means that you need to print the k-th plot before each `insertPlot`.

```
library(openxlsx)
# A test data set
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(Perc=runif(n), Quintiles=runif(n), 
                 Answer=sample(1:2, size=n, replace=T), 
                 Group =sample(1:5, size=n, replace=T))

List1 <- split(df, df$Group) 
ListGraphs <- lapply(List1, function(x) {
     ggplot(x, aes(x=Quintiles, y=Perc, group=Answer, color=as.factor(Answer))) +
     geom_line(size=2) +
     theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom", 
           legend.key = element_blank())
}) 
wb <- createWorkbook() 
for (k in seq_along(ListGraphs)) {
  name <- addWorksheet(wb, names(ListGraphs)[k]) 
  plot(ListGraphs[[k]])   # Plot the k-th graph before insertPlot
  insertPlot(wb, sheet=name)                     
} 
saveWorkbook(wb,"a.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]